# When I put node .\index I get the error (error Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token)

Tags: javascript, discord.js

This is my code and I'm trying to make a discord bot to learn about coding and I don't know. What to do because this is my first project

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.client();

client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('Ready!');
});

client.login('NzQ3MTQzNzczNDY0NTU5NzE2.X0Kl3A.86aCrGafWyTORGVVSTcyDS4bqlY');
```

the error that i get when i just put node index.js is

```
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:968
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module '[discord.js'
Require stack:
- C:\Users\Joey\Desktop\dsbot\index.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:965:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:841:27)

    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1025:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:72:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Joey\Desktop\dsbot\index.js:1:17)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1137:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1157:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:985:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:878:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [ 'C:\\Users\\Joey\\Desktop\\dsbot\\index.js' ]
}
```

the new error i get is

```
C:\Users\Joey\Desktop\dsbot\index.js:2
const client = new Discord.client();
               ^

TypeError: Discord.client is not a constructor
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Joey\Desktop\dsbot\index.js:2:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1137:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1157:10)

    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:985:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:878:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47
```

the newest error

```
(node:18644) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error [TOKEN_INVALID]: An invalid token was provided.
    at WebSocketManager.connect (C:\Users\Joey\Desktop\dsbot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:133:26)
    at Client.login (C:\Users\Joey\Desktop\dsbot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\Client.js:222:21)
(node:18644) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not
handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (reje
ction id: 1)
(node:18644) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Comment: Edit your token out. You should never reveal your token to anyone else, I highly recommend you to regenerate your token now.

Comment: I think Discord automatically resets every token they found on the internet, so no worry, but @Elitezen is right, you should absolutely NEVER paste a token like this in a public forum: instead put some gibberish text or a placeholder so that one can understand what's going on 

Comment: Careful now. You should have recieved an email from Discord about your token having been found on the Internet. Besides all that, here is a youtube series from a channel which was very helpful to me to get started on my first bots :
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4Np2fJOdXjE&list=PLdnyVeMcpY7_IiC977keSLBXXJG_I3vUo This one is being regularly updated, since it covers discord.js v12 (the latest version).

Comment: yea i already changed my token once i submitted the post :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe the command you're looking for is:

```js
node index.js
```

---

Also, I agree with the comments. **Never** post your token online. People will be able to log into your bot and do/say whatever they want. Luckily Discord is pretty good about this, and have probably automatically reset your token by now.

Comment: i did that one and now its saying require stack

Comment: oh yea sorry. i put it at the top of my post :D

Comment: Are you sure you wrote `require('discord.js')` and not `require('[discord.js')`?

Comment: oh yea oops. but now that i do it i get a new error :o ill post it this time

Comment: the "C" in Client has to be capitalized.

Comment: this is actually insane now there is another error when i do this. how could i have messed up so much :/

Comment: That just means your token is invalid. Try regenerating it.